# Migration of Google Project to Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, google-console-developer, google-play-services, firebase-console

Will importing a Google Project into Firebase interfere with or break the operation of any legacy applications using the related APIs? For example, we currently use the Youtube APIs to allow users to upload videos to a website. Would this be affected after migrating?

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't break the legacy applications since the API key etc will remain the same. I've migrated the Google Project to Firebase project. I used to use Google Cloud Messaging API. Now I migrated from GCM to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) and the `projectId`, `projectNumber` or `SenderID`, [API Key](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key), all remained the same. I didn't have to change anything on the server side as well and it worked out of the box.

Also if you import your Google Cloud Project to Firebase Project, the project on Google Cloud Platform still remains and you can keep using the same API's for now in similar manner. It seems that only for GCM, Google App Invites and AdMob, you can 'choose' to upgrade to corresponding Firebase services.