# Migrate from a Google API Project to Firebase (Android or iOs)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, migration

I read the article about migrating a google api project to firebase:

[doc](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/google-android)

Has the migration of an Google API project to firebase an effect on the functionality of the current productive version of an App in Google Play or iOS? Will the defined API Keys (Oauth2 client ids, Google Places API keys, server keys...) still work after firebase migration?

Thanks!
Smilingm

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible duplicate Question which was answered here:

[Migration of Google Project to Firebase Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214791/migration-of-google-project-to-firebase-console)

I will try to migrate soon and check if problems occur. Update follows...